# Wrapping function for fscanf didn't work

Tags: c++, scanf, variadic-functions

I try to making a wrapping function around fscanf but didn't understand why it didn't work,

```
char name[255] = {0};
fscanf(inFile, "%s", &name);   // This work fine
```

but when I do this

```
int WrapFScanF(File* inFile, const char* format, ...) {

    int rv;
va_list args;

va_start(args, fmt);
rv = fscanf(file, fmt, args);
va_end(args);

return rv;
}

char name[255] = {0};
WrapFScanF(inFile, "%s", &name);   // This work fine
```

It didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to read about [`vfscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vfscanf) . Use it instead of `fscanf()` when you have a `va_list` as `va_list` cannot be used like that.

Comment: Thanks, but under VS2008, it seems it didn't support vfscanf().

Comment: @NachoChip: You are right, and that's unfortunate. `v*scanf()` functions are C99, and MS will not support it any time soon. Citing a [MS speaker](http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/): _we recommend that you consider using a different compiler such as Intel or gcc_